# Is there an uninstall command in setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I have a package that adds a directory into the  `sys.prefix + 'share/'` directory on `python setup.py install`. This is done with a custom `setuptools.install` command.

I'd like to know if there's a way to remove what I added when I uninstall the package.

Is there an uninstall hook in setuptools?

Comment: There does not seem to be a uninstall command in _setuptools_' `setup.py`. Advice: you should not use `setup.py` to install or uninstall, those usages are somewhat deprecated and not recommended. You should use `python -m pip install` `python -m pip uninstall`. Also you should not customize the setuptools `install` command.

Comment: Probably if you reformulate your question to mention what you are trying to do, why you are adding things to that `share` directory, we might be able to offer better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that this is what the `data_files` parameter of `setuptools.setup` is for. No need for a custom install command.

https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files

This will register files to be installed or uninstalled.

Comment: Note that `data_files` is also not recommended and somewhat deprecated as far as I know. https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html?highlight=data_files#keywords